# A game-theoretic chess puzzle -- Proof verification

Tags: proof-verification, puzzle, game-theory, chessboard

I recently came up with the following chess puzzle (which has almost nothing to do with one's Chess skills):

> **Puzzle:** Consider a variant of chess where black has to start with $1...e5$ regardless of white's first move. All other rules remain unchanged. Prove that in this variant, white can at least force a draw.

I have told this it to several people, and some of them seem to think that my solution is wrong.

> **Solution**: consider the position where white has a pawn on $e4$ and black has a pawn on $e5$, with all other pieces at their starting
>   positions. Let's refer to this position as $P$, the player with the
>   next move as player $1$, and the other player as player $2$. Then
>   according to Zermelo's Theorem, starting from position $P$, either player $1$ can force a win, or
>   player $2$ can force a win, or they can both force a draw. We consider
>   them one by one:
>
> - If they can both force a draw starting with position $P$, all white has to do is to reach this position by playing $1.e4$, as black will
>     have to go $1...e5$ which creates position $P$.
> - If player $1$ can force a win, white has to reach position $P$ and be the player with the next move. In this case, white will still play
>     $1.e4$, which is followed by $1...e5$. At this point, position $P$ has
>     been reached and white is the player with the next move.
> - If player $2$ can force a win. White will play $1.e3$ and after black plays $1...e5$, white will play $2.e4$. Now we're in position
>     $P$, and it's black to move. This means that black is player $1$,
>     which makes white player $2$.

They argue that position $P$ is not the same position when player $1$ is white and when it is black. When player $1$ is black, their king is on their right side, whereas when player $1$ is white, their king is on their left (same goes for the queen).

My answer is that starting with any symmetric position (like $P$, or the starting position in standard chess or [this position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc6q1.png)) if white had a winning (drawing) strategy $\mathcal{A}$ starting with position $P$, then if black were to start instead, it would have a winning (drawing) strategy $\mathcal{A}'$ where for every move (black's or white's) in $\mathcal{A}$, row $i$ is replaced with $9-i$, where $1 \leq i \leq 8$ (e.g. 
$Nc6$ would become 
$Nc3$). Thus position $P$ *is* the same regardless of who starts.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should notice that there are no possible en passant captures (since that's the one potential difference between your 1. e4 and 2. e4 positions).

Comment: wait...is e5 specifically relevant here? could this be like d6 instead? Nf6?

Comment: wait, what am I misunderstanding here? ' Prove that in this variant, white can at least force a draw.' --> This assumes white knows the outcome of position $P$. I'd say white can at least force a draw assuming white knows the outcome of position $P$. I think this is different from saying white can at least force a draw.

Comment: @BCLC:  what is special about e5 (it could be any two step pawn move) is that white can reach the position corresponding to P on the move or off it at his option.  d6 and Nf6 do not have this property.  This argument just says white can force at least a draw but gives no indication of the strategy needed.  The game tree is finite, so in principle you could prune it to find the optimal move(s) for each side at each position.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks!

Comment: @RossMillikan re the force a draw, ah so it's basically like zermelo's theorem itself which doesn't give a strategy but says white can either force at least a draw or black can force a win?

Comment: @RossMillikan wait re e5, i don't get it. i think i get that e4 can be replaced by another move but it has to be a 2 step pawn move, but why can't e5 be replaced by any other black move?

Comment: @BCLC Because position $P$ has to be symmetric, like the one I linked in the question (otherwise the argument made in the last paragraph wouldn't hold).

Comment: ah ok so this argument holds for any 2 step black pawn move but only 2 step black pawn moves because of 1 - symmetry and 2 - the ability to do 2 x 1 pawn moves to each the desired symmetric position?

Comment: @Micah what's the relevance of en passant here pls?

Comment: @BCLC: The proof makes reference to "the position" where the e pawns are in the center and all other pieces are in their starting configuration. What I was getting at is that specifying the placement of pieces on a chessboard does not uniquely specify a game state; in general you need some additional data like whether or not there is a legal en passant capture. As it happens, this particular placement of pieces on the board does determine a unique game state, but you have to actually make that argument to make the proof watertight...

Comment: @BCLC:  the point of position P is that it is either a win for the next player, a win for the previous player, or a draw.  We are using the symmetry of the position to replace the usual requirement in impartial games that each player have the same moves available.

Comment: @Micah what? i mean, what's the relevance of en passant in the case of e4 e5 vs e3 e5 e4?

Comment: In general if you move from e2 to e4 there may be an en passant capture available, while if you move from e3 to e4 there will not. So in order to claim that the two positions are symmetric and therefore that the strategy stealing proof applies, you need to verify that in this case there is no en passant capture available. (I am not saying that this verification is particularly difficult, just that this is something which must be considered.)

Comment: @Micah Agreed. We'd also need to mention that the kings have not moved (otherwise castling would be illegal thereafter) since position $P$ could potentially be reached with one of the kings moving, e.g. $e3, e5, Ke2, Nf6, Ke1, Ng8, e4$.


For instance, this argument would not work for what Magnus Carlsen played a little over 3 weeks ago, where he went $Ke2$ right after $e4, e5$: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVCst6vyV80
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVCst6vyV80

Comment: PkT what i understand is that the kings would not have moved because $P$ is either e4 e5 or e3 e5 e4. what am i misunderstanding? sure $P$ can be reached in that way if we don't consider the rest of your argument but your argument consists of exactly 2 ways to reach $P$...right?

Comment: @Micah No offense, but I reached a 1900 rating on an online chess site once, so I think I know what I'm talking about. And while I do have a master's degree in applied maths, I didn't quite learn any game theory (although I self-studied a bit from scott p. stevens' lectures). This part however i think is 99% chess and 1% maths, sooo...:

Comment: @Micah I don't get it. how is there en passant possible from e2 to e4 while e2 to e3 to e4 there won't? if a black pawn comes to 4th rank, then the e pawn will not be able to capture it regardless. and if the e pawn goes to 5th rank, then the e pawn will still be able to do en passant captures regardless of how it came to the 5th rank (and how it came to 4th rank)

Comment: @Micah i've also double checked the [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant#Conditions) and i did not see anything about how the captur*ing* pawn must move 2 squares on its 1st move. i know however that the captur*ed* pawn must move 2 squares on its 1 move

Comment: ...yes, when I said "there may be an en passant capture available" I meant "there may be an en passant capture available *for black*". In this particular case there isn't because black can't have moved his d or f pawns far enough (or indeed at all). The point I was making is that general arguments of the form "white can choose to end up this position either with or without tempo, by moving a pawn either once or twice" require you to worry about the possibility of an en passant capture, because if such a capture is possible than "this position" is not actually the same position in both cases.

Comment: @Micah (i wasn't notified since you didn't tag me) i actually don't really quite get it still. did you mean the cases where $P$ arises besides 'e4 e5' and 'e3 e5 e4' ? can you please give an example PGN to describe what you mean?

Comment: PkT btw why don't you just say bongcloud?

Comment: @BCLC Right, I did not think people outside the chess community would know of it, especially that it is considered a 'joke' opening rather than a real one.

Comment: PkT 1 - but bongcloud has a wiki page XD 2 - right ok anyway, @Micah hasn't replied yet. could you possibly provide an answer to the relevance of en passant? i think micah is referring to something besides the 2 cases in your answer.

Comment: @BCLC: Suppose you had exactly the same puzzle, except that the starting position was rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/3P4/3p4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1 instead of the usual starting position. Then the argument in the question does not go through without modification, because the two positions being considered aren't actually symmetric (in the 1. e4 e5 game, white could continue 2. dxe6, while in the 1. e3 e5 2. e4 game, black could not continue 2 ... dxe3). As it happens, black still does not have a win in this position, but the proof in this case is at least one sentence longer.

Comment: And I would not want to rule out the possibility that there's some symmetric but very weird near-zugzwang position where black does have a forced win even with the required move. At the very least, you need to prove some general theorem like "adding extra legal moves to a chess position can never convert a win into a loss" to show that this is impossible.

Comment: @Micah why would we consider that the starting position is rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/3P4/3p4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1  ? i was actually expecting you would reply with some PGN from the original starting position instead of FEN for a different starting position. soooo i'm kinda lost here.

Comment: @BCLC: Why shouldn't we consider that starting position? It's a perfectly good puzzle that you can't stop me from thinking about!

More seriously, what I'm saying is: 1) the solution given in the question looks like it should apply to my modified puzzle with the new starting position as well, but 2) it doesn't without a bit of modification. If you want to make the argument totally airtight you need to say something which either applies to both positions, or which distinguishes between them.

Comment: @Micah but in starting position and with the argument given, there is no need to consider en passant, and the argument is correct?

Comment: The conclusion of the argument is correct. I think to be totally precise the argument should explicitly say "there is no need to consider en passant captures". And I'm now done talking about this; please do not continue to tag me.

Comment: @Micah you still didn't tag me. anyhoo so do you now take back 'you should notice that there are no possible en passant captures'?

Comment: @BCLC: I'm now done talking about this; please do not continue to tag me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a fine [strategy stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument) argument.  The mirror image of the board does not matter as castling is defined in a way to respect the mirror image and all other moves are symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the name! Apparently, I still cannot upvote :)